Issues creating a thumbnail stream for dash.js?
https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-MediaPlayer.html#provideThumbnail
I understand correctly that when called with a timestamp. Will it return the miniature?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429301/ffmpeg-dash-with-tiles-of-thumbnail-images
<AdaptationSet contentType="image" id="5" mimeType="image/jpeg">
  <BaseURL>
    http://origin.yourdomain.com/storage/thumbs/video_id/
  </BaseURL>
  <SegmentTemplate duration="120" media="$RepresentationID$/number/tile$Number%03d$.jpg" startNumber="1"/>
  <Representation bandwidth="12895" height="432" id="thumbnails_256x144" width="1024">
    <EssentialProperty schemeIdUri="http://dashif.org/guidelines/thumbnail_tile" value="4x3"/>
  </Representation>
</AdaptationSet>

I have 1 audio stream, 5 video streams. Is it also possible to add a stream of thumbnails to them and it will be possible to work with provideThumbnail?
ffmpeg -i {file} -deadline good -movflags +faststart -map_metadata -1 \
    -c:a libopus -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -map 0:a:0 -b:a:0 128k \
    -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 scale=-1:144,fps=30 -b:v:0 60k
    -init_seg_name "init-$RepresentationID$.$ext$"\
    -media_seg_name "sg-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$" \
    -dash_segment_type webm \
    -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 9 \
    -adaptation_sets "id=0, streams=v id=0, streams=a" \
    -f dash {path}manifest.mpd

In the example with ffmpeg, 1 audio stream and 1 video stream, how to add a stream of thumbnails?
